# Get current playback time of AudioSource before disabling the object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-source

Is there a way to get the current playback time of an audio played by the audiosource before its parent becomes disabled?

I have this gameobject that has audiosource component that play a sound and I want to get the current playback time of the sound before the gameobject is disabled. I've try to get it on `void OnDisable()` but it doesn't work.

```
void OnDisable()
{
AudioSource audiSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
Debug.Log(audiSource.timeSamples);
}
```

This script always return zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are basically creating a new reference to the `AudioSource` object.

Your class should like like this:

```
AudioSource _audioSource;

void Start(){
_audioSource=GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void OnDisable(){
Debug.Log(_audioSource.timeSamples);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the AudioSource has a sound attached to the Clip property. AudioSource.timeSamples only seems to work if the sound is applied to the Clip field, either in the inspector or via script. If you use AudioSource.PlayOneShot you'll always get 0.